# When deleting a row, the edit action part ignores the UITableViewRowAnimation setting

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

If I side swipe on a table view row to delete it then the row does not dismiss as a complete entity - by this I mean the edit action portion of the cell always dismisses itself by sliding upwards, but the rest of the cell dismisses itself according to whatever value has been set for UITableViewRowAnimation.

So for example if the row below is deleted using `deleteRows(... .left)` then the white portion of the row will slide off to the left of the screen but the UNBLOCK part behaves separately - it always slides up the screen, irrespective of the UITableViewRowAnimation value used in deleteRows.

[image]

Code is as follows:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "UNBLOCK") { action, index in
        self.lastSelectedRow = indexPath
        let callerToUnblock = self.blockedList[indexPath.row]
        self.unblockCaller(caller: callerToUnblock)
    }
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.tableViewRowDeleteColor()
    return [deleteAction]
}

func unblockCaller(caller:Caller) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        Model.singleton().unblockCaller(caller) {(error, returnedCaller) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if let lastSelectedRow = self.lastSelectedRow {
                        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [lastSelectedRow], with: .left)
                    }
                }
                ...
```

Does anybody know how to make the whole row move consistently together?

Comment: My initial thought is that this has something to do with cell reuse. Perhaps the selection, or editable state of the cell isn't being reset between cell uses. Try looking at documentation and seeing if you can reset the "swipeable" state after using your cells. Perhaps putting something in prepareForReuse would help, or in the tableview datasource editingStyle method. I know this is a broad answer, but hopefully it's a start in helping find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct. These two objects behave as separate entities. You cannot control the animation of the `UITableViewRowAction` button as it drawn outside of the `UITableViewCell` frame.

See the `UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView` layout in this **Captured View Hierarchy**. (Notice how the `UITableViewCell` frame, in *blue*, doesn't encompass the `UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView`, in *red*):
[image: Expanded view showing that the cell is not clipping the button]

#### Fix

Hide the editing button prior deleting the cell. It will be erased prior the cell deletion animation, before the rest of the cells scroll upward.

```
func unblockCaller(caller:Caller, indexPath:IndexPath) {
    // Perform the deletion
    // For example: self.blockedList.remove(at: indexPath.row)

    // if error == nil...
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: false)
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
    }
}
```

[image: Animation of the deletion]

#### Additional Comments

1. I recommend *not* using state variables to keep track of which cell must be deleted (`self.lastSelectedRow = indexPath`). Pass the path to the worker method instead for a better isolation of the tasks.
2. Use the standard appearance whenever possible ; if the UNBLOCK button is but a red control, prefer the `style: .destructive` and avoid custom color schemes. The `editActionsForRowAt` becomes a **single line**:
   `self.unblockCaller(caller: self.blockedList[indexPath.row], indexPath: indexPath)`

Comment: Thanks for you answer.